# Pyes Elastic Search No Results Return

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I am following the get-started tutorial of pyes, the code can finish, but there is no search results returned to my screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pyes import *

def main():
    print 'hello world'
    conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200')
    # delete the existing index/database and create the new one
    try:
        conn.indices.delete_index("test")
    except:
        pass
    conn.indices.create_index("test")

    mapping = {
            'mpn':{
                    'index': 'analyzed',
                    'store': 'yes',
                    'type': 'string'
            },
            'manufacturer':{
                        'index': 'analyzed',
                        'store': 'yes',
                        'type': 'string'
            },
            'timestamp':{
                    'type': 'date'
            },
            'stock':{
                    'store': 'yes',
                    'type': 'integer'
            },
            'price':{
                    'store': 'yes',
                    'type': 'float'
            }
    }

    conn.indices.put_mapping("test-type", {'properties':mapping}, ["test"])


    conn.index({'mpn':'apple', 'manufacturer':'manufacturer1', 'timestamp':'2009-11-15T14:12:12', 'stock':100, 'price':1.2}, "test", "test-type", 1)
    conn.index({'mpn':'apple', 'manufacturer':'manufacturer1', 'timestamp':'2009-11-16T14:12:12', 'stock':99, 'price':1.2}, "test", "test-type", 2)
    conn.index({'mpn':'apple', 'manufacturer':'manufacturer1', 'timestamp':'2009-11-17T14:12:12', 'stock':90, 'price':1.2}, "test", "test-type", 3)
    conn.index({'mpn':'apple', 'manufacturer':'manufacturer1', 'timestamp':'2009-11-18T14:12:12', 'stock':140, 'price':1.2}, "test", "test-type", 4)

    conn.indices.refresh("test")

    q = TermQuery('mpn', 'apple')
    results = conn.search(query=q)
    for result in results:
        print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the code, it only returns the hello world.

Totally new to elastic search and any feedback would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: It worked for me with pyes 0.20.1 and elasticsearch 0.90.2